# How to easily extract ID from iTunes URL using Python

Tags: python, regex

iTunes URLs look like the following:

```
http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/break-of-dawn/id472335316?ign-mpt=uo%3D
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/monopoly-here-now-the-world/id299110947?mt=8
http://itunes.apple.com/es/app/revista-/id397781759?mt=8%3Futm_so%3Dtwitter
http://itunes.apple.com/app/id426698291&mt=8"
http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/respect-the-bull-single/id4899
http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/id6655669
```

How can I easily extract id number?

Example:

```
get_id("http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/brawn/id472335316?ign-mpt=uo")

#returns 472335316
```

Comment: **Regex** is the thing you should be searching for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import re

def get_id(toParse):
    return re.search('id(\d+)', toParse).groups()[0]
```

I'll let you figure out error handling...

Comment: +1: For mentioning error-handling. I think you should use `r'id(\d+)'` with that backslash, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex something like `"/id(\\d+).*"`; the first capture group will have the id number in it. I think you can also write it as `r"/id(\d+).*"` in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Without regex (for no reason):

```
import urlparse

def get_id(url):
    """Extract an integer id from iTunes `url`.

    Raise ValueError for invalid strings
    """
    parts = urlparse.urlsplit(url) 
    if parts.hostname == 'itunes.apple.com':
       idstr = parts.path.rpartition('/')[2] # extract 'id123456'
       if idstr.startswith('id'):
          try: return int(idstr[2:])
          except ValueError: pass
    raise ValueError("Invalid url: %r" % (url,))
```

#### Example

```
print get_id("http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/brawn/id472335316?ign-mpt=uo")
# -> 472335316
```